# Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException - Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, php-ini

I use PHP 7.0, I also use Apache on my Ubunutu server.

I've already updated my `php.ini`

```
cat /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini                                                                                                                                                                                              
post_max_size = 2000M                                                                                                              
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
memory_limit = 4000M
```

I already restart the service

```
service php7.2-fpm restart
```

I still getting

> Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException

[image: enter image desmiss?on here]

What do I still miss? Is there anything I should do with the `Apache` ?

Comment: Maybe there is a value set in .htaccess?

Comment: Do you know what filed I should check ?  I will check .

Comment: Look at your .htaccess file or virtual host file for [this option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), and try to restart apache too.

Comment: `ValidatePostSize` middleware compares `request()->server('CONTENT_LENGTH')` & `ini_get('post_max_size')`. Doing a dump of these can help you debug more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

> **Note:** I was updating the wrong file as I would have use `Nginx`.

Since I use **Apache**, I should update this file instead

```
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

---

After made changes to the right file, and restart, every working as expected now.

```
cat /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini | grep -E 'post_max_size|upload_max_filesize|memory_limit'                             
memory_limit = 500M                                                                                                         
post_max_size = 500M                                                                                                        
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```